# Crear una funcion para validar SOLO numeros y en cierto rango

Tags: c

Necesito crear una función para validar el ingreso de SOLO números y al mismo tiempo poder hacer que esa función pueda validar si el numero ingresado está en un determinado rango.

Ejemplo especifico:

Quiero que la persona solo ingrese un numero entre 1 y 1000 y que muestre un error para que lo reingrese por si ingreso una letra o un numero fuera del rango.

```c
int Only_Integrers_Validation(char mensaje[], char error[],int min,int max)
{
    int banderaOperando = 0;
    char operandos[T];
    int longitud;
    int i;
    int operando;

    do
    {
        if(banderaOperando == 1)
        {
            printf("%s",error);
            banderaOperando = 0;
        }

        printf ("%s",mensaje);
        scanf ("%s", operandos);
        longitud = strlen (operandos);
        for (i=0;i<longitud; i++)
            if (!isdigit(operandos[i]))
            {
                banderaOperando = 1;
            }



    }while(banderaOperando == 1);

    operando = atoi(operandos);

    while(operando < min || operando > max)
    {
        printf("%s", error);
    }

   return operando;
}
```

A la hora de querer hacerlo funcionar no lo hace, como todavía no domino bien el `isdigit` ni el uso de la cadena de caracteres lo que busco es hacerlo dentro de una función para que si la persona ingresa una letra o un numero fuera del rango lo pida de nuevo.

Comment: ¿Puedes insertar el código que llevas hecho hasta ahora? ¿Qué errores te salen? No pretendas que te hagamos la tarea de la escuela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quiero que la persona solo ingrese un numero entre 1 y 1000

Entonces deberías empezar por leer lo que ha introducido el usuario:

```
scanf ("%s", operandos);
```

Vale, ya has leído el valor que pretendes validar, el siguiente paso debería ser recorrer `operandos` para garantizar que todos los caracteres se corresponden con dígitos numéricos:

```
scanf ("%s", operandos);

for( char* ptr = operandos; *ptr != NULL; ptr++)
{
    if (!isdigit(*ptr))
    {
        printf("La secuencia %s no es un numero valido", operandos);
        return;
    }
}
```

También tienes que convertir la secuencia en un número, eso lo puedes hacer una vez hayas validado que todo está correcto:

```
for( char* ptr = operandos; *ptr != NULL; ptr++)
{
    // ...
}

int resultado = atoi(operandos);
```

Ahora ya puedes validar si el número está en el rango esperado:

```
if (resultado < min || resultado > max)
{
    printf("El numero %d no esta en el rango (%d, %d)\n", numero, min, max);
    return;
}
```

Ahora, ya si, podemos integrar todo lo que hemos hecho en un bucle para que se le pidan valores al usuario hasta que introduzca uno válido:

```
int resultado = 0;
int valido;
do
{
    // Inicialmente asumimos que el usuario va a introducir un numero valido
    valido = 1;

    scanf ("%s", operandos);

    for( char* ptr = operandos; *ptr != NULL; ptr++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(*ptr))
        {
            printf("La secuencia %s no es un numero valido", operandos);
            valido = 0; // En vez del return actualizamos el flag
        }
    }

    // comprobamos el valor del flag, no tiene sentido hacer mas validaciones
    // si el dato no es numérico
    if (valido == 1)
    {
        resultado = atoi(operandos);
        if (resultado < min || resultado > max)
        {
            printf("El numero %d no esta en el rango (%d, %d)\n", numero, min, max);
            valido = 0;
        }
    }
} while (!valido);

return resultado;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, dado que soy muy nuevo en C te queria preguntar algo, tu codigo con null no funciona, me lo marcaba en rojo:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

pero puse NULL y me lo agarró hasta que compilé:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Pero cuando compilo me tira este error:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ram7.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnJ43.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHFYd.png

si yo a ese != NULL le coloco un 0 funciona, por que?

Comment: @GiovanniLucchetta perdona, contesté desde el móvil y se me fueron las mayúsculas,  es NULL, es una macro cuyo valor es 0. Ahora lo arreglo

Comment: Ah ok! no hay problema, pero te decia que aunque use el NULL En mayuscula me sigue apareciendo "Warning: comparison between pointer and integrer.

Osea que no se podria hacer con NULL y con 0 funciona bien

Comment: @GiovanniLucchetta no estarás compilando en c++?

Comment: No eferion, tengo un codigo bastante grande y si estuviese en c++ ya me habria dado cuenta, si querés te puedo mandar la foto de como queda el codigo cuando le pongo el NULL y el ERROR!

Comment: @GiovanniLucchetta el uso de NULL nunca debería darte ese warning ya que es una macro que se convierte en 0, que es lo mismo que estás poniendo tú. Si te da ese warning debe ser por otro motivo. Piensa que las macros las trata el precompilador, y ese no te genera este tipo de mensajes